# When do I need to worry about floating-point error in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, floating-point

JavaScript doesn't have different types for integers and floating point numbers. When working with "integers", does this mean I need to worry about round-off error?

For example, if I want to know when a number `x` is divisible by 3, is it okay to write

```
x % 3 == 0
```

or do I need to do a floating-point-style compare such as:

```
x % 3 <= 0.5
```

Any insight would be appreciated.

(If I do need to do the inequality there, what about checking if a passed argument to a function is equal to 1; can I write `x === 1` or not?)

Comment: modulus arithmetic does not just work on integers-

4.5%.5 returns 0, as does .6%.3.

Answer (score 4):

If you're working with integers, it is usually safe. However, some floating-point arithmetic can act very strangely. If you perform floating-point operations on the number before using modulus, even if the logical result will always be an integer, you should use:

```
Math.floor(x) % 3 === 0
```

But if it's always an integer, like this:

```
var x = 52;
if(x % 3 === 0) { // safe
}
```

Then that's fine. In regards to your second question, the `===` identity operator is also safe to use between numbers. For example:

```
function x(y) {
    return y === 7;
}

alert(x(7.0)); // true
```

Works correctly.

Comment: Thanks. Do you have a source for this?

Comment: @Ben Alpert: Just fact. Try this: `1.265 * 100000`; it gives `126499.99999999999` which you must round up or down to give the correct result.

Comment: Sorry, I meant a source for the "usually safe" for int-types.

Comment: @Ben Alpert: When you initialize a variable to a constant value, it will always have that value unless it exceeds the proper precision. This works for all values; object literals, numbers, arrays, strings... and you can always rely on that. No source though.

Answer (score 1):

if x is an integer, you can do the modulus as written first.

and '===' is only necessary if you want to fail, say, a string "1" or boolean true, but pass an integer 1; otherwise '==' should be sufficient.

Comment: In most programming languages, "1" == 1 returns false; it makes sense for JavaScript to do the same.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript doesn't expose different types for ints and floats, but does have the concept of them.  the built-in function `parseInt` can be used to force a number (or any other number-like value, including the string "32.06"!) to be an integer.  It truncates, rather than rounding, floating-point values.

Comment: Do you have a source for that it has the concept of them?

Comment: the existence of the parseInt and parseFloat functions, primarily =)

Comment: Yes, but `parseInt` just gives you a float that happens to be equal to an integer.  They're not separate data types.

Comment: @dan04: That's why it's a concept. "JavaScript doesn't expose different types for ints and floats, but does have the concept of them."